# WordPress or php Odd Syntax error and google chrome ajax login

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, google-chrome

so i'm doing a search for tables and i have a 1500 line of code and it works perfectly fine but i have two problem one is my code errors like this :

```
if ($wpdb->get_var('show tables like "' . placeholders . '"') == placeholders) {
    foreach ($placeholders as $placeholder_) {
        $Gplaceholders[$placeholder_] = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . placeholders . '` WHERE `placeholder` = "' . $placeholder_ . '"', ARRAY_A)['value'];
    }
}
```

error:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected [ in ******
```

other is my ajax login and registration works perfectly fine on Mozilla but on chrome it just sniping and not doing anything , has anyone encounter this kind of problem in chrome?

Comment: Probably a version issue with a version of PHP that doesn't support array dereferencing, ie < 5.4.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Gplaceholders[$placeholder_] = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM `' . placeholders . '` WHERE `placeholder` = "' . $placeholder_ . '"', ARRAY_A)['value'];
```

Your first placeholders doesn't need to be wrapped in ' . . ' - try:

```
$Gplaceholders[$placeholder_] = $wpdb->get_row('SELECT * FROM `placeholders` WHERE `placeholder` = "' . $placeholder_ . '"', ARRAY_A)['value'];
```

Are you sure you want to have 'G' in '$Gplaceholders' ?